# wireless device to send data with low latency up to 1km

Tags: rf, wireless, mobile, device

I need a device about the size of a phone with 2 buttons, the device will be used to let a server know the outcome of an event (2 possible outcomes).
A mobile phone app would be the obvious choice but I want to reduce the latency as much as possible and it also needs to be more reliable than mobile internet.

I was thinking that it might be possible to create a device that sends the outcome by a radio transmitter to a receiver connected to a computer up to a 1km away with a fibre optic internet connection.

the device would need to operate for several hours.

is this realistic? how much knowledge and skill would be needed to create something like this?

thanks

Comment: Just google "1km wireless transmitter". It gave me some decent results.

Answer (score 2):

This transmitter/receiver pair, from [Electronics-DIY.com](http://electronics-diy.com/store.php?sel=kits), transmits data up to 4800 baud at 433 MHz.  The manufacturer claims a range of 1 km.  Cost is very reasonable, $10 for both modules.

[image]

The receiver current consumption is 5 mA.  The transmitter consumption varies between 5 mA and 45 mA, obviously the latter when it is actively transmitting.  With a couple of AA cells, using a boot regulator to boost the battery voltage up to 12V (for maximum transmit range), you should be able to get 6 to 7 hours of life out of one set of batteries on the transmit side, and much longer on the receive side (which runs on 5V).